# Redefine a class to add new features or find a way around

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I would like to redefine a class of the core wpf API (UIElement), I don't want to inherit a class.

In have a project on the MS Kinect, I've re-implemented cursors mapped with the user's skeleton's hand. I've implemented similar event to those that the mouse raised (enter an elements, leave an element...). I want that all elements inheriting from UIElement to get some attached properties:

```
  KinectCursorEnter, KinectCursorMove...
```

and some Properties:

```
    public bool IsKinectLeftCursorOver { get; set; }
    public bool IsKinectLeftCursorDirectlyOver { get; set; }
    public bool IsKinectRightCursorOver { get; set; }
    public bool IsKinectRightCursorDirectlyOver { get; set; }
    public bool IsKinectLeftCursorCaptured { get; set; }
        ...
```

I know there's a lot ways to mess things up if I change such a class, but that's at this level that I want to add thoses properties. (`UIElement` already implement stuff such as `MouseEnter`, `StylusEnter`...). The Kinect is an input device as any other (mouse, stylus, keyboard...)

I've try:

- To inherit UIElement and add the feature , but then I would have to
  reimplement all the Classes.

I've take a look:

- If there's such a thing as Ruby's open classes
- If I can use extension ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx))
- If I can use in any way Adapter pattern

So far I'm using use:

- An interface and I redefine all element: I have a `KinectButton` that
  inherit from `Button` and implements `IKinectInputElement` but I can't do that for some class which are `sealed` (Rectangle, Ellipse...)

I thing I a few months (years?) MSFT will implement those kind a Properties and method in Wpf API. But for now I need a way around.

PS: I don't want to control the mouse with one of the hand of the user. there is one mouse, I want to have two cursors. and I have events such as : KinectLeftCursorEnter, KinectRightCursorEnter and so on..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to extend the class.

Comment: I've take a look to extension, the problem is: when the constructor of the class is called I want to add handler to events: this.KinectCursorEnter += new KinectCursorEventHandler(OnKinectCursorEnter);
 And the corresponding handler. I don't want such a feature in another method, because I just want to put my control on my wpf page, and make thigs work

Comment: For that i think you have no other option than inherit from the class.

Comment: If think That I will keep my interface and inherit the visual element that I need. I found a way to handle KinectUIElement and non-KinectUIElement at the sametime at the KinectCursorManager Level. I let this question open to see if there's any other answer. Anyway @Asif thanks for your answer I'll up your answer as soon as I've enough reputation (extension works most of the time in that case).